# How to connect to AWS SQL Server and run a query in AWS GLUE

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I wanted to connect to AWS SQL Server and run a SQL query joining multiple tables. I tried to automate that using Visual ETL but I keep getting error 'An error occurred while calling o91.getDynamicFrame. key not found: url'

Can someone assist on how can I fix this or what's the script to run from spark or python?

Comment: You need to create connection for sql server. You can create a connection and use it in glue job or you can use jdbc url, usename and password to establish the connection.